# How to create a git repository with idempotence by chef?

Tags: git, chef-infra

I want to create a git repository if it doesn't exist yet, and if exists, then sync the repository like this.

Command line:

```
$ mkdir /var/git-repo/my_project.git
$ cd /var/git-repo/my_project.git
$ git --bare init --shared
```

And chef:

```
git "/opt/my_project" do
  repository "/var/git-repo/my_project.git"
  action :sync
end
```

How can I write git init command with keeping it idempotent by chef?

*Edit*

I found `git init` is safe to execute to existing repository from git document.

> Running git init in an existing repository is safe. It will not
>   overwrite things that are already there. The primary reason for
>   rerunning git init is to pick up newly added templates (or to move the
>   repository to another place if --separate-git-dir is given).

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init

So, I decided to run `git init` every time without condition.

Comment: Another option to consider is the deploy resource http://docs.opscode.com/resource_deploy.html

Comment: You should move your edit to an answer and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm wondering what the problem is.. the description for `action :sync` [says](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_git.html): "Use to update the source to the specified version, or to get a new clone or checkout." - so why do you want the `git init` at all? Because of the bare repo?

Comment: Ignoring idempotence is a bad habit. You should add an `only_if` block that checks e.g. if the file `/opt/my_project/.git/config` exists. It works to call `git init` over and over again, but it contradicts with chef's idea of doing changes only, if really needed.